# Arch Linux Gnome problem

Tags: xorg, x11, gnome, startx

I have a quite weird problem I just cannot get rid off.
I am using ArchLinux and as I am from Germany the german keyboard layout and such.

So when I start Gnome via startx it is said that Gnome is not able to work I must logout. 
I have get rid of this problem two times but just until I restart. After the rebot the same problem occurs and I am no longer able to use Gnome. I have get rid of the problem as long as I do not reboot but I do not excatly know what is causing this problem. 
First I get warnings from XKEYBOARD:

```
XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
Compat map for group 2 redifined.
Compat map for group 3 redifined.
Compat map for group 4 redifined.
Using new definitions.
Type "ONELEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 Symbols.
```

The it says:

```
xinit:Connection to X server lost
```

And my log file says the following, but I have shorten it:

```
[user@Work log]$ grep -e WW -e EE /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old
[  1281.385] Current Operating System: Linux Work 3.16.3-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Sep 17 21:54:13 CEST 2014 x86_64
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  1281.386] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/OTF/" does not exist.
[  1281.386] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1/" does not exist.
[  1281.386] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/".
[  1281.386] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi/".
[  1281.394] (WW) intel(0): Detected a hung GPU, disabling acceleration.
[  1281.395] (WW) intel(0): loading DRI2 whilst the GPU is wedged.
[  1287.428] (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Then I aslo found some posts on similar problems so I have added three files to the directory */etc/X11/xorg.conf.d*. The first time this has solved the problem I guess, but it still does not work.

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-keyboard.conf

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "de"
        Option "XkbVariant" "nodeadkeys"
EndSection
```

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-keyboard.conf

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "de"
        Option "XkbVariant" "nodeadkeys"
EndSection
```

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier "Intel Graphics"
   Driver "intel"
   Option "NoAccel" "True"
EndSectio
```

And regenerate the locales with locale-gen.

Please help me, as I just do not know what to do anymore. :D

Running xfce4 without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So 
I have finally solved this problem. I needed to deinstall the xf86-video-vesa driver with:

```
pacman -R xf86-video-vesa
```

And then I needed to change the */etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf* file to:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier "Intel Graphics"
   Driver "intel"
   Option "DRI" "False"
EndSection
```